# Select odd rows from a specific column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a large `df` with a specific `numeric` column named `Amount`.

```
df = data.frame(Amount = c(as.numeric(1:14)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to select odd rows. So far, I have tried with the syntax below but I always get this error messages:

```
df$Amount[c(FALSE, TRUE),]
```

*Error in df$Amount[c(FALSE, TRUE), ] : incorrect number of dimensions*

```
seq_len(ncol(df$Amount)) %% 2
```

*Error in seq_len(ncol(df$Amount)) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(ncol(df$Amount)) :
  first element used of 'length.out' argument*

```
odd = seq(1,14,1)
df$Amount[odd,1]
```

*Error in P20$Journal.Amount[even, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions*

```
P20$Journal.Amount[seq(2,length(14), 2),]
```

*Error in seq.default(2, length(14), 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument*

**My question is:** Is there a way I can do this directly? I tried with the solutions of questions previously posted but so far, I keep having these error messages.
`BaseR` preferably.

Comment: You are selecting a vector.  So, you don't need `,`  `df$Amount[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`  If the rows are selected, then `df[c(FALSE, TRUE),, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: df$amount is not a `data.frame` but a vector, thus `[` behaves differently (no comma) needed: `df$Amount[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row/column` index is used when there are dim attributes.  `vector` doesn't have it.

```
is.vector(df$Amount)
```

If we extract the vector, then just use the row index

```
df$Amount[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
```

---

If we want to subset the rows of the dataset,

```
df[c(FALSE, TRUE), 'Amount', drop = FALSE]
```

In the above code, we are specify the row index (`i`), 'j' as the column index or column name, and `drop`  (`?Extract` - is by default `drop = TRUE` for `data.frame`.  So, we need to specify `drop = FALSE` to not lose the dimensions and coerce to a vector)